# Python program reading number input as string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, integer, calculator

I'm trying to make a simple calculator in Python. I'm asking for 2 numbers and then operating based on the operational character they choose. However, the variable is turned into a string type so I can't add, subtract, etc.

This is the code:

```
a = input("Enter first number")
print(a)
b = input("Enter second number")
print(b)
op = input("Choose operation by entering +, -, x, or /")

if(op == "+"):
    print(a+b)

elif(op == "-"):
    print(a-b)

elif(op == "x"):
    print(a*b)

elif(op == "/"):
    print(a/b)    
else:
    print("Sorry; input the correct operational character")
```

Comment: sorry the code looks weird in the question

Comment: Just cast `a` and `b` to `int` or `float`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Answer (score 2):

example:

```
a = input("Enter first number")
a = int(a)
```

Another way:

```
a = int(input("Enter first number"))
```